# KQL Query to determine if an account is in an Azure Active Directory Group

Tags: azure-active-directory, kql

I am wondering if there is a way to determine whether an account is included in a specific Azure Active Directory Group using KQL?

This is the KQL query that flags the alert:

```
SecurityAlert
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SystemAlertId
| where SystemAlertId in("ed518654-9ac0-b869-e962-58b940a86959")
```

This example flags up a mass download event but it's being triggered by a known account used to back up data. I have multiple accounts like this for different scenarios.

I thought if I created an AAD group and added these accounts, is it possible to reduce the noise of the alerts using a KQL query where the account performing the action is a member of a specific group? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this:

`print current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=mygroup@mycompany.com')`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but I want it for the the user that triggered the alert. Not for the user running the query.

Comment: Then you'll need to update your ingestion pipeline to ingest the correct data into Azure Data Explorer (ADX). ADX can run queries on data that you ingested, but it can't guess which data you actually meant to ingest.